# What could be wrong with my function?

Tags: php

I am making a new script and am currently building the database class. I have created a function which checks a user's IP address. When I went to test it out, I was left with a blank page rather than the `die('It Worked');`.

I don't like posting a load of code however it would make more sense if I posted my class so far.

`class.Database.inc`

```
<?php
      require_once('config.php'); // Configuration file

    /**
     * MySQLi database; only one connection is allowed. 
     */
    class Database {
     // Database credentials from config file
      private $_DATABASE_SERVER = DB_SERVER;
      private $_DATABASE_USER   = DB_USER;
      private $_DATABASE_PASS   = DB_PASS;
      private $_DATABASE_NAME   = DB_NAME;

      private $_connection;
      // Store the single instance.
      private static $_instance;

      /**
       * Get an instance of the Database.
       * @return Database 
       */
      public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$_instance) {
          self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
      }

      /**
       * Constructor.
       * Database connection (server, user, password, name)
       */
      public function __construct() {
        $this->_connection = new mysqli($this->_DATABASE_SERVER, $this->_DATABASE_USER, $this->_DATABASE_PASS, $this->_DATABASE_NAME);
        // Error handling.
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
          trigger_error('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
      }

      /**
       * Empty clone magic method to prevent duplication. 
       */
      private function __clone() {}

      /**
       * Get the mysqli connection. 
       */
      public function getConnection() {
        return $this->_connection;
      }

     /**
     * DATABASE IP CHECK FUNCTION 
     */
        public function checkIp($user_ip) {
            $db = self::getInstance();
            $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

            $sql_query  = "SELECT ip FROM ";
            $sql_query .= "ip_address WHERE ";
            $sql_query .= "ip = '$user_ip'";

            $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                die('It Worked!');
            } 
        }
    }
    ?>
```

The problem is with the function located towards the bottom of the file, the `checkIp();` function.

I have created a `test.php` file with these contents.

```
<?php
require_once('class.Database.inc.php');

Database->checkIp('1');
?>
```

I'm not sure whether I've attempted to access the function incorrectly or whether it is something else. The value 1 is in the database, in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: A Singleton. Don't do that, just... don't. PS: classes don't `die` and seldom `trigger_error`, they throw `Exceptions`

Comment: @MartinBean Nothing in the error_log

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Changed it to trigger_error, still nothing...

Comment: Why not add an `else` part and see if maybe `$result->fetch_assoc()` is evaluating as `false`y?

Comment: @MattKent: _No!_ A method should _not_ `trigger_error`, unless it is that class's job. This class' task is to connect to, and query, the DB. If something goes wrong, it should `throw new RuntimeException` or another exception. Besides: `Database->checkIp('1');` is impossible: the `checkIp` method is _non-static`, you need to get an instance of the class first, before you can call non-static methods. If you insist on the horror of singletons: `$db = Database::getInstance(); $db->checkIp();`. Oh and singleton constructos are `private`, but the `__clone` method is `public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid the singleton and create a `Database` object when you need one.  Instead of `Database->checkIp('1')` you should be using an instance of `Database` rather than calling the function more static like.  Also, your `checkIp` function should just access the `getConnection` function via `$this` since you're already inside the class and don't need to create a new instance.

You may want to ensure error reporting is on so that it's easier to identify problems:

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

```
<?php
  require_once('config.php'); // Configuration file

/**
 * MySQLi database; only one connection is allowed. 
 */
class Database {
 // Database credentials from config file
  private $_DATABASE_SERVER = DB_SERVER;
  private $_DATABASE_USER   = DB_USER;
  private $_DATABASE_PASS   = DB_PASS;
  private $_DATABASE_NAME   = DB_NAME;

  private $_connection;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   * Database connection (server, user, password, name)
   */
  public function __construct() {
    $this->_connection = new mysqli($this->_DATABASE_SERVER, $this->_DATABASE_USER, $this->_DATABASE_PASS, $this->_DATABASE_NAME);
    // Error handling.
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
      trigger_error('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Get the mysqli connection. 
   */
  public function getConnection() {
    return $this->_connection;
  }

 /**
 * DATABASE IP CHECK FUNCTION 
 */
    public function checkIp($user_ip) {
        $mysqli = $this->getConnection();

        $sql_query  = "SELECT ip FROM ";
        $sql_query .= "ip_address WHERE ";
        $sql_query .= "ip = '$user_ip'";

        $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            die('It Worked!');
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

usage:

```
<?php
    require_once('class.Database.inc.php');
    $database = new Database();
    $database->checkIp('1');
?>
```